# uib-btn-radio not working with $scope but works with "controller as" syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple btn-group like so

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" 
    ng-model="radioModel" 
    ng-repeat="playerClass in playerClasses" 
    ng-class="{{ playerClass.buttonClass }}" 
    uib-uncheckable='false' 
    uib-btn-radio="{{ playerClass }}">{{ playerClass.className }}</label>
</div>
```

With this in the controller

```
$scope.playerClasses = cardFactory.getClasses();
$scope.radioModel = { className: 'value', buttonClass: 'value'};
```

But whenever I clicked one of the buttons the radioModel doesn't change, which caused more than one button to be active

I switched $scope with "controller as" syntax and that fixed the issue but the thing is I used $scope syntax through out the project and I don't want just one controller to have "controller as" and the others to have $scope.

My question is, is there any way to make uib-btn-radio to work with $scope instead of "controller as"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use 'controller as' then have a dot in your model variable

`ng-model="data.radioModel"`

There is a good explanation here (items #2 and #3)
https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes

Comment: I thought it was only because of angular-ui-bootstrap, turns out I wasn't looking in the right place, This is the correct answer, thanks a ton!

Comment: nice, I´ve been crazy looking what was my problem. I forgot the model controller was the $parent. Thank u very much

Answer (score 2):

Each template instantiated by `ng-repeat` directive creates its own child scope, and can use `$parent` to access the scope surrounding `ng-repeat`. So the quick fix is:

```
ng-model="$parent.radioModel"
```

Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzs2sr54/